# open popup after 10 second of staying in the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I open a popup after visitor stay in the webpage for 10 seconds? I want to use this popup - http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/ and I want to it will open after someone stay for 10 second in the webpage.

Comment: What have you tried to do? If you look for `setTimeout` and `window.open` I'm sure you can work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        modalClose: false,
        opacity: 0.6,
        positionStyle: 'fixed' //'fixed' or 'absolute'
    });
    },10000);
```

Comment: but this is not working.

Comment: please share your code. 
1.Be sure you have jquery library added to your page.
2. The plugin js file added.
3. Wrap the above code inside $(document).ready() function

Comment: here is the code - http://jsfiddle.net/Lytv1vv5/

Comment: I had a little mistake and finally this have worked!